# javascript/jquery:: get text value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, text

I have a dom structure like so:

`<a>abc<span>def</span></a>`

I am wanting to get the text from the `<a>` tag when I click it.

However when using this.text I get `abcdef` instead of just `abc`.

How would I got about getting the text value of just the `<a>`?

Am I going to have to do it this way and then do a `substr()` to the length of the `<span>`'s text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option:

```
var text = $("a").contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE; }).text();
```

Comment: I noticed Nick's one below makes a clone, hence an extra object. Does this method also make an extra object?

Comment: No it doesn't create an extra object.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by getting the [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) from a [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) without those child elements in there, like this:

```
$("a").click(function() {
  var text = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/xftmW/).

Answer (score 0):

If that is the actual structure (the `<a>` text coming before the `<span>`), you could do this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var txt = this.firstChild.nodeValue;
});
```

This will be very fast, but again, it assumes that the text always comes first, and that it is not segmented by other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a library to walk the dom, you could just ask the browser to do it for you:

```
var string = element.innerText || element.textContent;
```

This should work in all webkit based browsers, firefox, ie and opera.

Comment: That will still give you "abcdef".

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
var text = $('a').text().replace($('a span').text(), '');
```